# Python + Selenium: How can click on "onclick" elements?

Tags: python, css, python-2.7, selenium, xpath

I have an "onclick" element in a webpage whose HTML reads as follows:

```
<a href="#" onclick="fastener('3625')">Fastener</a>
```

I want to search this element using the string "fastener" or "Fastener" using Python + Selenium. The number "3625" will change depending on previous inputs, and hence cannot be searched for.

I tried the following, but in vain:

```
br.find_element_by_css_selector("a[@onlick*='fastener']").click()
```

Please suggest ways to do this. Thank you!

P.S.: I am using Python 2.7, with Chrome WebDriver and Chrome v62.

Comment: `@onlick` is an XPath syntax. In CSS you should use `a[onlick*='fastener']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To search the element with text as **Fastener** you can use either of the following options :

- Through **Fastener** :

  ```
  br.find_element_by_link_text("Fastener").click()
  ```
- Using **onclick** through **fastener** (xpath):

  ```
  br.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@onclick,'fastener')]").click()
  ```
- Using **onclick** through **fastener** (css_selector):

  ```
  br.find_element_by_css_selector("a[onclick^='fastener']").click()
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code for that:

```
br.find_element_by_link_text("Fastener").click()
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Using [capybara-py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/capybara-py):

```py
page.click_link("Fastener")
```

Capybara is designed to provide this and many other similar helper methods, such as one might need to write acceptance tests from the perspective of end users:

```py
page.fill_in("Street", value="123 Main St")
page.select("United States", field="Country")
page.choose("Expedited shipping")
page.click_button("Place order")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use contains to search element

```
//a[contains (@onclick='fastener')]
```

OR

```
   //a[contains(text(),"Fastener")]
```

Comment: I got the following error with both your suggestions:
`selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified`